# how to mock ITable with a concrete type

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq

I am writing unit tests for a repository that use System.Data.Linq DataConext object to get Table of entities from database. Here's the code :

```
public class ForumRepository : IForumRepository
{
    protected Table<Forum> DataTable;
    IDataContextWrapper DataContext;

    public ForumRepository(IDataContextWrapper DataContext)
    {
        DataTable = DataContext.GetTable<Forum>();
    }

    public Forum GetForumById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return DataTable.Single(f => f.tblForumID.Equals(id));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And here's the wrapper implemention :

```
public class DataContextWrapper<T> : IDataContextWrapper where T : EpixForumDataContext, new()
{
    private readonly T db;

    public DataContextWrapper()
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        db = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
    public DataContextWrapper(string connectionString)
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        db = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(t, connectionString);
    }

    public Table<TableName> GetTable<TableName>() where TableName : class
    {
        return (Table<TableName>)db.GetTable(typeof(TableName));
    }
```

I want to test the repository method.

```
public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Can_Get_Forum_ById()
        {
            //arrange
            Forum dummyForum = new Forum() { tblForumID = 1};
            Mock<ITable<Forum>> tableMock = new Mock<ITable<Forum>>();
            tableMock.Object.Attach(dummyForum);
            Mock<IDataContextWrapper> mock = new Mock<IDataContextWrapper>();
            mock.Setup(m => m.GetTable<Forum>()).Returns(tableMock.Object) ;

            //act
            ForumRepository repos = new ForumRepository(mock.Object);
            Forum resultForum = repos.GetForumById(1);

            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual(resultForum.tblForumID, 1);
```

Where Forum is an auto generated class. I want to setup the forum for Table so that when I do a GetTable on the ContextWrapper I get the table of forums. I do not know if Table.Attach would attach the Forum to the Table or not. Also when I run the test it says

> 'Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract class or non-sealed
>   class'.

Have I got it all wrong?

Comment: is this line correct?  `Mock<ITable<TableName>> tableMock = new Mock<ITable<TableName>>();` ... I don't see `TableName` type on your code

Comment: @pollirrata : Sorry about that. It should be Mock<ITable<Forum>. Editing question right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see several issues with what you're trying to do.

1. The posted code does not compile

   `IDataContextWrapper.GetTable` returns `Table<T>`, so you can't set it up to return a mocked `ITable<T>`. An `ITable` is *not* a `Table`, it's the other way around. This leads me to my next point:
2. `IDataContextWrapper.GetTable` should return an `ITable<T>`, not `Table<T>`.

   This will let you mock the return result, since `Table<T>` is [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358844.aspx) (Moq can't mock sealed classes, which is probably why you got the error you mentioned).  It's also good design to [program to interfaces](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/01/01/interface-based-programming.aspx) rather than concretes.
3. You shouldn't expect the call to `Attach` to do anything

   You're trying to call a method on a mocked interface like you're expecting it to behave as if something has implemented it.  The mock's methods will only do what you tell them to, so in this case (with [Loose behavior](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior)) it will just do nothing with that call.  Instead you should set up what you expect the table to do, but that leads me to:
4. You can't set up the call to `Single` because it's an extension method

   Moq [doesn't support setting up extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2295960/1698557), since they're static methods.  However, you can setup the call to `GetEnumerator`, which is what `Single` calls anyways.  You'll need to [mock the `IQueryable<T>` members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7048511/1698557) though, since that's what `Single` is really going to hit.

So, after resolving point 1 above,  your test in the end should look like this:

```
[Test]
public void Can_Get_Forum_ById()
{
    // arrange
    Forum dummyForum = new Forum { tblForumID = 1 };
    IQueryable<Forum> forums = new List<Forum> { dummyForum }.AsQueryable();

    Mock<ITable<Forum>> tableMock = new Mock<ITable<Forum>>();
    tableMock.Setup(p => p.GetEnumerator()).Returns(forums.GetEnumerator());
    tableMock.Setup(r => r.Provider).Returns(forums.Provider);
    tableMock.Setup(r => r.ElementType).Returns(forums.ElementType);
    tableMock.Setup(r => r.Expression).Returns(forums.Expression);

    Mock<IDataContextWrapper> mock = new Mock<IDataContextWrapper>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.GetTable<Forum>()).Returns(tableMock.Object);

    // act
    ForumRepository repos = new ForumRepository(mock.Object);
    Forum resultForum = repos.GetForumById(1);

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(resultForum.tblForumID, 1);
}
```

Note that this is a good, not great test.  You could replace the call to `Single` with a call to `First` and it would still pass, but obviously be wrong in general.  You should at least add a negative of this test, i.e. no object is returned if the Id does not match.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for a very good explanation. However, I didn't understand one thing. That Table is not an Itable but its the other way around. As far as I remember,if a dog class implements an Animal interface then dog is an animal but animal is not dog.

Comment: This line `mock.Setup(m => m.GetTable<Forum>()).Returns(tableMock.Object);` gives the same invalid arguments error. `Test Name: Can_Get_Forum_ById
Result Message: 
Test method EpixForum.WebUI.Tests.UnitTest1.Can_Get_Forum_ById threw exception: 
System.NotSupportedException: Type to mock must be an interface or an abstract or non-sealed class.
Result StackTrace: 
at Moq.Extensions.ThrowIfNotMockeable(Type typeToMock)
   at Moq.Mock`1.CheckParameters()
   at Moq.Mock`1..ctor(MockBehavior behavior, Object[] args)
   at Moq.Mock`1..ctor()
   at EpixForum.WebUI.Tests.UnitTest1.Can_Get_Forum_ById()`

Comment: @user3527975 You're right, I screwed up which "is not" the other, fixed in an edit.  The code compiles and runs for me.  Did you change the return type of `GetTable` to `ITable<T>` (point #2), and `tableMock` is a mock of `ITable<Forum>`?

Comment: Yes. The IDataContextWrapper.GetTable returns an ITable<T> in my code. `namespace EpixForum.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IDataContextWrapper 
    {
        ITable<T> GetTable<T>() where T : class ;
    }
}`

Comment: @user3527975 That error is saying you're trying to mock a sealed class, which `Table` is.  What type is `tableMock`?  It should be `Mock<ITable<Forum>>`, not `Mock<Table<Forum>>`.  It's also being thrown in a Mock constructor, not on the line setting up the return value.

Comment: tableMock is Mock<ITable<Forum>>.

Comment: @user3527975 Then you have code that I don't.  Feel free to post more code, anything that's different or revised, as an edit to your question and I can help further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59532/discussion-between-user3527975-and-patrick-quirk).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Forum dummyForum = new Forum() { tblForumID = 1};
            Mock<ITable> tableMock = new Mock<ITable>();
            tableMock.Object.Attach(dummyForum);
            Mock<IDataContextWrapper> contextMock = new Mock<IDataContextWrapper>();
            contextMock .Setup(m => m.GetTable<Forum>()).Returns((ITable<Forum>)tableMock.Object) ;

            //act
            ForumRepository repos = new ForumRepository(mock.Object);
            Forum resultForum = repos.GetForumById(1);

            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual(resultForum.tblForumID, 1);
```

Comment: Okay this solves one of my problem. I still get an error at line `contextMock .Setup(m => m.GetTable<Forum ()).Returns(tableMock.Object) ;` saying the Returns method has invalid arguments. Got any ideas on this. I am returning a table as should a context wrapper return.

Comment: I believe is because tableMock.Object is of type object and you are expecting to get a Table<Forum>. Maybe you need to cast tableMock.Object, I updated the answer

Comment: I did try casting the object to table. It still gives the same error. Is this line correct - `tableMock.Object.Attach(dummyForum)` ? Since Table.Attach attaches the entity to the datacontext. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548978(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sometimes the compiler gets confused about the Returns call in Moq and can't figure out the correct type.  Try setting it specifically -- `Returns<ITable>(/* snip */`