# Mock a call to IQueryable using moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to moq a repository I have which is defined as:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
    Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null,
    bool disableTracking = true
)
```

Is there a way to mock this?  I want the query to execute, using the mock data I supply the repos.  I'm not sure how to tell MOQ that when I call GetAll I want it to still run the query that is passed in, but do it against the dataset I supply. so it's not going to the db but against the mock set which I've configured. I'm able to create the data, it contains 12 records, but I want the getall moq call to execute its query and filter it to just the 2 that should be returned.

The actual service where the call happens is:

```
var list = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<CASE_ACTIVITY>()
    .GetAll(predicate: x => 
        x.SM_SITE_ID == siteId && 
        x.CMS_USER_ID == userId && 
        x.IS_DELETED == "N" &&
        x.Appointment.IS_DELETED == "N" &&
        x.Appointment.IS_ARCHIVED == "N" &&
        x.IS_ARCHIVED == "N" &&
        (
            (x.Appointment.APPOINTMENT_DATETIME.HasValue &&
             x.Appointment.APPOINTMENT_DATETIME.Value.Date == DateTime.Today.Date) ||
            (!x.Appointment.APPOINTMENT_DATETIME.HasValue &&
            x.ACTIVITY_STATUS_ID == _appSettings.CASE_ACTIVITY_STATUS_ID_PENDING)
        )
    )
    .Include(x => x.Activity_Lookup)
    .Include(x => x.Appointment)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Cms_Client)
    .Include(x => x.Cms_Case)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking classes that implement IQueryable with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048511/mocking-classes-that-implement-iqueryable-with-moq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have enough control over the `GetRepository()` method to make *it* return your mock repository, mocking the method itself is fairly straightforward (if a little verbose).  I just dumped the `GetAll` method into an interface called `IRepository`, and this is what the mock looks like.  Inside of the `Returns` method, you have access to each of the parameters to execute or ignore as you please.

```
  var mock = new Moq.Mock<IRepository>();
  mock.Setup(a => a.GetAll<int>(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<int, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<int>, IOrderedQueryable<int>>>(), It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<int>, IIncludableQueryable<int, object>>>(), It.IsAny<bool>()))
    .Returns<Expression<Func<int, bool>>, Func<IQueryable<int>, IOrderedQueryable<int>>, Func<IQueryable<int>, IIncludableQueryable<int, object>>, bool>((param1, param2, param3, param4) =>
    {
      return new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.AsQueryable();
    });

  var result = mock.Object.GetAll<int>();
```

From here, we can't help much without seeing more code.  In abstract terms, though, you'll take your `mock.Object` (which is of type `IRepository`) and feed it to whatever collection GetRepository() draws from.  Also note, of course, that I used an int for the generic parameter -- you'll replace that with whatever type you're using.  It may be possible to make a mock that accepts generic parameters, but that hopefully won't be necessary!

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case Where method will no be applied when:

var res = myRepo.GetAll<int>().Where(x=>x > 2).ToList() // 1,2,3 will be returned instead of 2,3

Is there any way to apply Where to result?