# How to test 'ToListAsync' with a IsFaulted, IsCanceled and IsCompleted test cases

Tags: c#, mocking, task, nunit

Hi guys I have a method like this:

```
public virtual async Task StartSearch()
{
    CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    Context = ContextFactory.Create();

    SearchResults = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            IsLoading = true;

            var resultTask = GetResults().ToListAsync(CancellationTokenSource.Token);

            while (!resultTask.IsCompleted && !resultTask.IsFaulted &&
                   !CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                Thread.Sleep(100);

            IsLoading = false;

            if (resultTask.IsFaulted)
                throw resultTask.Exception ??
                      new Exception("Some error.");

            return resultTask.IsCompleted && !resultTask.IsCanceled ? resultTask.Result : null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            IsLoading = false;
            throw;
        }
    }, CancellationTokenSource.Token) ?? SearchResults;
}
```

I wonder how could I mock up a Task (with all those IsFaulted, IsCompleted, IsCaneled fields) which I get from .ToListAsync() method? 
I've found that they are not virtual so I cannot create a Task object to simply mock them.
Additional question is if it gives me something if I create my own dummy class and mock it for a test.

What are your suggestions? Maybe you don't want to mock it?

For now I only tested this to check if my method will return some data.

EDIT:

```
public abstract IQueryable<dynamic> GetResults();
```

and some exemplary implementation:

```
public override IQueryable<dynamic> GetResults()
{
    var query = Context.Table.AsQueryable();

    query = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Field)
        ? query
        : query.Where(table => table.Field.Contains(SomeFilter));

    return query.Select(
            table => new
            {
                table.Field1,
                table.Field2,
                table.Field3
            }).OrderBy(table => table.Id);
}
```

Comment: Why are you polling the task returned by `ToListAsync` instead of just awaiting it? If you want to simulate a failed/cancelled operation you can mock the call and use a task returned by `Task.FromException` or `Task.FromCancelled` in your tests.

Comment: How does `GetResults()` method look like?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I've added this code to the original post.

Comment: You can have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048511/mocking-classes-that-implement-iqueryable-with-moq/8533489), how to mock `IQueryable` interface